# Current location using an IP address and the iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, location, ip-address

In an application there is extreme use of the current location, and I got success in using the current location, but I am not able to find the current location in a house or basement, etc. So what I think that we can use is the IP address to get the location and then I will get the longitude and latitude.

I am not getting the current location while using the IP address (I can find the IP address) in iPhone. How do I  sort out the issue.

Comment: This question already exist on Stack&nbsp;Overflow: *[Get IP address of the current Wi-Fi access point on a iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538365)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using the same, and it works fine when I am outside of my house, but in case I am inside the house or in basement it doesn't get the current location.

I am saying while using the IP address we can get the location so we will have a current location and then we can get the longitude and latitude of a particular location using g.

Answer (score 1):

First check whether your [GPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Positioning_System) is on in your device. You can use CLLocationManager to get your current location.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    //Get your current location here
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
       didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{

}
```

Use these methods to get the location.

Comment: I am using the same...n i works fine when i am outside of my house....but in case i am inside the house or in basement it didnt get current location i am saying while using ipaddress we can get location so we will have a current location then can get longitude and latitude of particular location using google api......

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the question is, but I think you have an IP address and you want to know which location is associated with it, right ? If so, you're out of luck. There are some databases to map these, but they can only tell you where the *owner* of the IP is located... and that is your ISP, not you (the customer).

On iOS, there's [Core Location](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html), doesn't that work for you ?

Comment: @DarkDust.....I am using Core Location but while sitting in house or in basement app runs but didnt get current location....i am saying i can get ipaddress of iPhone and using that i want to know the location and later will generate longitude and latitude of location using google api......